# SQLite db update recreate table keep values

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with one table which I need to update in a new version of my database.

In the first version of the table I have a id and a txt value like this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table_name id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, txt TEXT")
```

But in the next version of the database I wand to add a lastchanged value which must be a TIMESTAMP with default value current time in epoch which I do with (strftime('%s', 'now')).

But since I can't add a column with default current time, according to this error:

**Cannot add a column with non-constant default (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN edited_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now'))**

I tought I could best recreate the data and copy it to the new database

```
// copy all data to single value something like a Cursor res maybe??
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name );
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table_name id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, txt TEXT, edited_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now'))");
// now insert the values into the recreated database
```

But for this i need to copy all data into a new table that does not exist simultanious. Is it posible to do this without looping and having to save every value separate and then inserting them seperately again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The general procedure is:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO table_name_old;
CREATE TABLE table_name( ... );
INSERT INTO table_name(col1, ..., coln) 
  SELECT col1, ..., coln FROM table_name_old;
DROP table_name_old;
COMMIT;
```